# Where should an absolute beginning programmer start?

Tags: python

Yea, I own a couple of Python, C++ and Java books. I'm 16 and pretty interested in programming, but I am kind of lost on where to start to get an idea of the basics. I want to know the in's and out's of programming. Any book and programming language recommendations? My only current experience is HTML (but that isn't really relevant) I've just recently started reading this Python book (as I've heard Python is a great beginning langauge) but I am having a hard time understanding some of the concepts. I think I need to take a step back.

I have my sights open for security type programming. Any tips and recommendations will be appreciated.

Comment: Could you collaborate on what you want to do with "programming"? Do you want to make games, make business applications? "security type programming" what's that suppose to mean?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2992208, http://stackoverflow.com/q/3096472, http://stackoverflow.com/q/2439638  and others seem relevant. I will note that regardless of what you eventually want to do with programming, the process of learning how to write basic programs will be pretty similar.

Comment: Security as in virus protection applications, maybe even security as in video game anti cheats. Applications that protect users from threats. That's just one area that I'm interested in.

Answer (score 5):

Follow these [Google Python Class](http://code.google.com/intl/es-AR/edu/languages/google-python-class/). Trust me, best way to begin, really! Video lectures, exercises, it's all in there and teached by the best: **Nick Parlante**

I followed those classes after knowing Python (quite well) and I still learned a lot!